# How to play team war in mobile Agar.io?

Tags: agar.io, mobile

I am playing Agar.IO for a long time on my laptop. When I heard that it was available for mobile, the first thing I did was download the game. Now my question is how do you play team war in mobile Agar.io?

Comment: Voting for close, not MineCraft related

Comment: @creulcat you can also change the tag...

Comment: @Mathias711 I was not aware arqade even had a tag for agar(io)

Comment: @creulcat the best moment to create one ;) (or in your case, ask in the comments for one)

Comment: Thanx for changing the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mobile version of the game only has the deathmatch (free for all) game mode at present.  Teams, experimental and party modes are not *yet* available.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is only Classic mode (FFA) and Rush mode. Team mode may be the next game mode out! Either that, or Experimental mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can play team mode by clicking rush both or how many friends you want to play with at the same time, once you are in check by seeing who is in the leader board, if you guys are in the same server, play through the 5 minutes than go to classic and find the server you guys have together. You get 3 different classic servers so check through all of them. This means that you could have 1, 2, or all 3 servers together and play in which ever one. If at this point you cant find each other, just close the tab and try it over again. After doing rush with your friend or friends beware that every server you will get is going to be full of huge people since they are most likely doing this method and teaming.